# In out parameter not working properly in Mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

I have make one procedure which has in and out parameter:

```
delimiter //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS empInfo ; 
CREATE PROCEDURE empInfo (tblname VARCHAR(50),
                          clName VARCHAR(50),
                          out total INT)
BEGIN

 SET @s = CONCAT("SELECT count(", clName ,") into total FROM ", tblname );
 PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
 EXECUTE stmt;

END//
```

Here I'm going to call above procedure in mysql.

```
mysql> CALL empInfo('emp','empid', @total);
```

It creates successfully, but when I use it - it doesn't work properly.

Comment: You've declared an OUT variable, but the query doesn't use it.  And the `CALL` statement doesn't include what we have to assume is a statement prior to that declares the `total` OUT parameter?

Comment: Doesn't work properly, what error does it throw?

Comment: can u please give me example..for same or re-correct given code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems alright to me but just dun work somehow
here is the workaround :

```
delimiter //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS empInfo ;
CREATE PROCEDURE empInfo (in tblname VARCHAR(255), in clName VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
  SET @s = CONCAT("SELECT count(", clName ,") into @total FROM ", tblname);
  PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
  EXECUTE stmt;
END//
delimiter ;
CALL empInfo('emo','empid');
select @total;
```

Comment: nice answer :)  , only the into @total need to be after the from tablename

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-storedproc.html) :
THE STORED PROCEDURE LIKE :

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS empInfo //
CREATE PROCEDURE empInfo ( IN tblname VARCHAR(50),
                          IN clName VARCHAR(50)
                         )
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN


 SET @s = CONCAT("SELECT count(", clName ,") as counter  FROM ", tblname);
 PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
 EXECUTE stmt;

END//
```

THE CALL IS LIKE

```
CALL empInfo('emp','empid');
```

Comment: UPDATED THE ANSWER AND CHECK, ITS WORK,

Comment: its echo to the screen the answer , after you call it !, if you see the example in the article i linked, you can use @ajreal answer with my remark also

Comment: just for further discussion - http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25970 the example here is working, but does not work when using `prepare` & `execute`, the problem is lied on that ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been running into the same situation. I wanted to generate a prepared statement and return a value (my natural inclination was to use a function, however apparently you cannot use `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` from within functions)

> SQL syntax for prepared statements cannot be used within stored
>   routines (procedures or functions), or triggers. This restriction is
>   lifted as of MySQL 5.0.13 for stored procedures, but not for stored
>   functions or triggers.
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

A slight variation to the solution posted by @ajreal, after you execute the statement you can set the value of your OUT param to the value of session variable used in the query.

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS empInfo;
CREATE PROCEDURE empInfo (in tblname VARCHAR(255), in clName VARCHAR(255), out total INT)
BEGIN
  SET @s = CONCAT("SELECT count(", clName ,") into @temp_Total FROM ", tblname);
  PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  SET total = @temp_Total; 
END//
DELIMITER ;
CALL empInfo('emo','empid', @total);
select @total;
```